# Drawing triangles from 3D triangulation

Tags: directx11

I'm trying to trianglulate 3D Points using DirectX11, so I triangulate 3D points then I try to draw triangles, the outcome of triangulation is std::vector, each Tri has a,b,c 3 values.

I don't see any output, I think I have a problem with the math..

here is my code:

```
void SetupTestVertices(ID3D11Device *pd3dDevice) {
    SimpleVertex *ptrV;
    int i;
    float *ptrToPoints;
    float scaleFactor = 1.f / (MAX_RAND * 0.5f);     // the test points are from 0 to MAX_RAND, so scale to 0 to 1.0
    int xyOffset = (MAX_RAND / 2);
    float brightness;                             // to make the triangles visually different from one another
    std::vector<R3> pts, pts2;
                              // to make the triangles visually different from one another


                               // create a random set of points to test the triangulation fuction
    if (g_numTestPoints > MAX_TEST_POINTS)  g_numTestPoints = MAX_TEST_POINTS;
    if (g_numTestPoints < 4)  g_numTestPoints = 4;
    ptrToPoints = testPointsXY;
    for (i = (g_numTestPoints * NUM_DIMENSIONS); i> 0; i--) {
        *ptrToPoints++ = ((rand() % MAX_RAND) - xyOffset) * scaleFactor;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < g_numTestPoints* NUM_DIMENSIONS; i++)
    {
        R3 pt;
        pt.c = testPointsXY[i];
        pt.r = testPointsXY[(i*3)+1];
        pt.z = testPointsXY[(i*3)+2];

        pts.push_back(pt);
    }

    std::vector<Tri> tris;
    //
    int ts = NewtonApple_Delaunay(pts, tris);

    // put those random points into a buffer for display
    ptrV = testvertexes;
    ptrToPoints = testPointsXY;

    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        // scale to between -1 and +1 since that all that this tutorial program was designed to show
        ptrV->Pos.x = pts[i].r;
        ptrV->Pos.y = pts[i].c;
        if (NUM_DIMENSIONS == 3)  ptrV->Pos.z = pts[i].z;
        else   ptrV->Pos.z = 0;
        // give the nodes different colors to make it easier to distinguish between the triangles, especially when they are filled
        brightness = (float)i / (float)30;
        ptrV->Color.x = brightness;
        ptrV->Color.y = brightness * 0.2f;
        ptrV->Color.z = brightness * 0.6f;

        ptrV->Color.w = 1.f;
        ptrV++;
    }

    std::vector<WORD> triangeList;

    triangeList.resize(tris.size() * 3);


    for (int i = 0; i < tris.size(); i++)
    {
        triangeList[i*3] = tris[i].a;
        triangeList[(i*3)+1] = tris[i].b;
        triangeList[(i*3)+2] = tris[i].c;

    }
    std::vector<WORD> lineIndex;

    lineIndex.resize(tris.size()*3*sizeof(WORD));
    int  l, t;
    for (l = 0, t = 0; t<tris.size()*3; t += 3) {
        // Each triangle has 3 lines, so D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINELIST needs 6 vertices
        // Each vertex has to be listed twice
        lineIndex[l] = triangeList[t];      l++;
        lineIndex[l] = triangeList[t + 1];    l++;
        lineIndex[l] = triangeList[t + 1];    l++;
        lineIndex[l] = triangeList[t + 2];    l++;
        lineIndex[l] = triangeList[t + 2];    l++;
        lineIndex[l] = triangeList[t];      l++;
    }
    ReleaseD3D_Buffers();   // from the previous cycle

                            // Fill in a buffer description for the triangle vertices
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(SimpleVertex) * g_numTestPoints;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    // Fill in the subresource data
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    ZeroMemory(&InitData, sizeof(InitData));
    InitData.pSysMem = testvertexes;
    pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &InitData, &g_pTestVector);

    // Fill in a buffer description for filled triangles
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = tris.size()*sizeof(WORD); // <---- numTriangleVertices comes from the function
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    ZeroMemory(&InitData, sizeof(InitData));
    InitData.pSysMem = static_cast<void *>(triangeList.data());      // <---- triangleIndexList is from the function also
    pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &InitData, &g_pTestVectorIndexBuffer);

    // Fill in a buffer description for drawing only the triangle outlines
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = lineIndex.size();   // <---- from the function
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    ZeroMemory(&InitData, sizeof(InitData));
    InitData.pSysMem = static_cast<void *>(lineIndex.data());
    pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &InitData, &g_pTriOutlineIndexBuffer);


}
```

Comment: For your outline buffer, your bytewidth seems to be calculated wrong.   Does lineIndex.size() return the array size, or the actual byte size of the array.  (maybe a furphy on my side btw).

Answer (score -1):

Please debug your code to detect where is the error. Then if you still doesn't figure it out what could be wrong, come to SO with a more detailed report than the actual about your problem in specific.